# Redirecting permalinks and loading the same content

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm currently serving articles for a blog, with permalinks in this format:

- http://domain.com/articles/46

This is the current **.htaccess** content:

```
# Permalinks
RewriteEngine on

# Articles (english url)
RewriteRule ^articles/?$ /articles.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^articles/([a-z_-]+)/?$ /articles.php?cat=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^articles/([a-z_-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /articles.php?cat=$1&id=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Now, I'm also translating all the articles into spanish, so I thought that having a permalink in spanish would be better. I need to setup an alias so that this redirection happens:

- /**articulos**/zombies => /**articles**/zombies
- /**articulos**/zombies/48 => /**articles**/zombies/48

In fewer words, all url requests that contain **/articulos/xyz/123** should be redirected to **/articles/xyz/123** without replicating the current htaccess structure. Thanks!

Comment: WHat does "without replicating the current htaccess structure" mean?

Comment: If `/articulos/zombies => /articles/zombies` redirection happens how will you serve Spanish content since URL has already become same as English one i.e. `/articles/zombies`

Comment: @JonLin by that I mean without replicating the whole rewrite rule structure.

Comment: @anubhava excellent point. There is a ?hl=en querystring variable. Perhaps, ?hl=es should be added if the user requests /articulos/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
# Permalinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^articulos/(.*) articles/$1 [QSA,ENV=SPANISH:true]

RewriteRule ^articles/?$ /articles.php [QSA]
RewriteRule ^articles/([a-z_-]+)/?$ /articles.php?cat=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^articles/([a-z_-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /articles.php?cat=$1&id=$2 [QSA,L]

Header set Set-Cookie "language=english; path=/;" env=!SPANISH
Header set Set-Cookie "language=spanish; path=/;" env=SPANISH
```

Comment: Worked great! Just one quick question, what should be added if I needed to send ?hl=es (only when using the articulos/ url) so that I force the article to be in spanish with that route?

Comment: @andufo I update code at my answer. You can just check language cookie in `articles.php`